# What is Tabular expression statement?

Tags: database, azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

When i am trying use Azure Data explorer , word : `Tabular expression statement` is often used. What is `Tabular expression statement`? how is it different from sql query language?

Comment: KQL (Kusto Query Language) is very different from SQL. You should start by reading here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/

Comment: Can you provide more details? What's the database and which kind of the database did you connect to?

Comment: Tabular typically means table data, as opposed to scalar data which is like a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Tabular expression statements` is defined in `kusto query language`. [Kusto query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/) is totally different from `sql query`. You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sqlcheatsheet) for differences.

For `Tabular expression statement`, it is defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tabularexpressionstatements). And here are some points of it:

> The tabular expression statement is what people usually have in mind
> when they talk about queries. This statement usually appears last in
> the statement list, and both its input and its output consists of
> tables or tabular data sets.
>
> Kusto uses a data flow model for the tabular expression statement. The
> typical structure of a tabular expression statement is a composition
> of tabular data sources (such as Kusto tables), tabular data operators
> (such as filters and projections), and potentially rendering
> operators.

It looks like this:

```
source1 | operator1 | operator2 | renderInstruction
```

A detailed example looks like this:

```
Logs | where Timestamp > ago(1d) | count
```